# NSPropertyListSerialization returning nil instead of serialized data

Tags: ios, objective-c, serialization

I am putting two `NSMutableArray` objects into an `NSDictionary` and trying to serialize, but the method call is returning nil. One array, `addresses`, is an array of `NSString` objects. The other, `engines` is an array of objects that each contain several data types. I am attempting to serialize using the following code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setObject:engAddr forKey:@"engAddr"];
[dictionary setObject:trainList forKey:@"engines"];
NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:dictionary
                                                          format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                errorDescription:&error];
```

Stepping through, the debugger shows the arrays are properly added to the dictionary, but after the line that should serialize the dictionary it shows `data = (NSData *) nil`.

Where am I going wrong? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I should add that I have also tried using `format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0` with the same result.

Comment: Engine contains the custom object right ? If yes, you need to conform to NSCoding protocol in that class unless that it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of objects does engines contain?
Plist supports only specific objects below.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-54303

If you want to serialize a custom object, convert it to NSData by NSKeyedArchiver.
To do that, objects must conform NSCoding protocol.

Comment: I thought `NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization...` was converting the objects within the NSArray to NSData. Is this incorrect?

Comment: all objects within NSArray must be specific class(NSString, NSNumber, NSData...). otherwise, convert it to NSData by yourself.